# Div1 covers Div2: how to check if the mouse is over the covered Div2?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a bit lost. I try to check if my mouse is over a Div which is covered by another Div. I search a vanilla js solution if possible.

I tried to use the elementFromPoint method, but it only seems to give me the top Div.
I also tried to mess around with the "onmouseover" Event, but I didn't found a solution either. Maybe I just overlooked something.

Any ideas how to solve this? I want a method to check if my mouse is over the smaller Div2 or not. I made a jsFiddle to show the situation. I made the covering Div 
translucent for easier understanding from the setup.

http://jsfiddle.net/y2L5C/

```
  <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>



   #div1 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#div2 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to see wich div is the mouse on??maybe if you clarify or give ideas of what is you proposal can help you, maybe hidding the div2 something like that???

Comment: you could make js that would add transparent div all over the place where there is div at under the main div that's over

Comment: @MickyScion: I want to drag an "item" div to a "container" div. I need a way to see if my mouse is over the container. My item do hide the container atm (like in the example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check if your mouse is over a `<div>` that is covered by another `<div>`, you can achieve this by declaring this code: `pointer-events: none;` to the `css` of the covering `<div>`.

For example:

```
<div id="under"></div>
<div id="over"></div>
```

Add this to your `css` file:

```
#over{ pointer-events: none; }
```

In that case, all pointer events for the `div` having the `id=over` will be ignored. You can now then add this code to test if its working.

Add this `JavaSCript` code:

```
$('#under').mouseover(function() {
    alert("Mouse is over the div having the id='under'");
});
```

Give it a try! Good luck!

Comment: Neat!  And actually something like `#under:hover { background-color: #fff }` works also.  http://jsfiddle.net/7T8K5/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty solution.  I'll leave it up to you to optimize it.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y2L5C/1/

```
var div2 = $("#div2"),
    width = div2.outerWidth(true),
    height = div2.outerHeight(true),
    offset = div2.offset(),
    top = offset.top,
    left = offset.left;

$(document).mousemove(function(evt) {
    if(evt.pageX <= (left + width) && evt.pageX >= left &&
       evt.pageY <= (top + height) && evt.pageY >= top) {
        $("#indicator").text("Over the div #2");
    } else {
        $("#indicator").text("NOT over the div #2");
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought of offering a solution like that. My concern was speed, but I did not test it.

Comment: You gotta start somewhere.  Optimization can come in the form of using DOM directly.

Comment: I agree. I have not benchmarked so I will be interested to hear results if any.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept. I do want to bring up that for plain CSS events there are plain CSS solutions such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996908/highlight-div1-and-div2-on-div2-mousover-highlight-nothing-on-div1-mouseover). However, if what you are looking to do is initiate Javascript events then the trouble is that onMouseOver is not going to trigger for `#div1` if `#div2` is on top of it.

One potential, very simple solution, is to create a script to copy the position of your `#div2` element and change the style to be a higher z-index. While JQuery might be "easier" to create this, you could certainly create a vanilla JS solution. [This script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) may give you a little guidance as to how you can find positioning. You can use `element.style` values in order to assign CSS values. If your element positions are declared by CSS then you can do something like this:

```
var div1 = getElementById('div1');
var div2 = getElementById('div2');
var newElem = document.createElement('div');
newElem.id = 'div2makefacade';
```

Now you can either utilize `newElem.style.top` etc. and assign `div2.style.top`'s value, or you can even assign a custom class which has the correct position values. When you initiate onMouseOver, you can do so on `#div2makefacade` rather than `#div2`, and perform actions on `#div2`

Answer (score 0):

well i made a function that perhaps it help you in some way, first in your view you have to load jquery librarie like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

and your css you have this

```
.visiblepanel{
  display: none;   
}

.visiblepanela{
  display: none;   
}
```

your script this, you have to add the hover function

```
$('#quickstart').hover(function() {
    $('#visiblepanel').toggle(); 
});

$('#quickstarta').hover(function() {
    $('#visiblepanela').toggle(); 
});
```

and your html body

```
<div id="quickstart">Div 1</div>

<div id="quickstarta">Div 2</div>

<div id="visiblepanel" class="visiblepanel">mouse encima div 1</div>

<div id="visiblepanela" class="visiblepanel">mouse encima div 2</div>
```

so it consist that when the mouse is over the DIV 1 it will show an advice that your mouse is there, and so on with DIV 2...i hope i could helped you...